# Powering an IBM x335

Tags: ibm, power-supply-unit

I've just purchased a second hand IBM X335 server in order to introduce myself to server hardware and management. Having never used such equipment before, I have much to learn, so please forgive me if these questions appear misguided, or the answers rather obvious.

On the rear of the server, there is a connector which I presume is for power, however I am lacking cables to connect the server to an outlet. What type of cable  and/or power brick will I need in order to power this server?

I have looked at some of the documentation for the server from IBM, but I am not confident that I could order the correct part based on my current understanding of that information.

I feel as though I may have put my foot in my mouth by asking, but one can not learn without inquiry.

---

#### Update 1

I have attached a photo of the connector which I believe to be the power connector. Appoligies for the bad photo, a combination of physical disability and an iPhone camera are to blame. Next to the power connector is what I assume are it's input requirements:

- 1.75 (not 35 I read it wrong)
- 200 - 240V
- 50 - 60Hz

[image: A close up photo of the three pronged power connector on my IBM x355 server.]

Comment: A reason for the down vote would be appreciated.

Comment: Not my downvote, but SF is tagged as "system administrators and desktop support professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity".  http://superuser.com probably would have been a better place for this question.

Comment: I will counteract that downvote.  Your question may be newbish but we all had to start somewhere.

Comment: @ziesemer In hindsight. That's a fair call, I'll get this migrated.

Comment: Its the VERY same connector a standard pc uses i think. If you live somewhere with 110 v power you may have issues tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a standard C14 connector.  And I'm sure you're missing a decimal in the amperage.  It's probably 3.5A, not 35A.  Just like almost any other modern computer PSU, it is designed to handle either 120V or 240V at either 50Hz at 60Hz.  (Keep in mind that halving the voltage will require 2x the amperage, so 120V would require more amperage.)

It isn't clear which voltage the amperage you listed is associated with, but other specs I've seen for this server place it at 2A @ 240V and 4A @ 120V.

You just need one of these:  https://www.google.com/search?q=AS+3112+C13+power+cable&tbm=shop

Comment: Agreed - 35A at 240V would be, well, insane for a single server. :)

Comment: @ziesemer You are correct. I misread the amperage entirely. Thank you for the link Also, thank you for counteracting the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the US, it should be a standard NEMA 5-15 or 5-20.

Comment: I'm in New Zealand. I assume it's somewhat different as we use AC power.

Comment: @Crippledsmurf - Without exception, utility power is always AC, though the voltage and frequency can change from country to country.

Comment: @ErikA I really should have known that. There's a reason I don't normally play with hardware, or things which relate to power :P

Answer (score 0):

You should start with identifying what the power connector actually *is*.

Posting a picture would help.

Odds are that [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320_C14#C13.2FC14_coupler) will have the connector you're looking for.

Comment: Will post a picture of the connector shortly.

Comment: Photo added as well as what I assume is operating power specifications.